# LaTeX build server with git

Tags: build, latex, make

I have a LaTeX project in git, there is a makefile. So basically a server would have to do this:

```
git checkout master
make > logfile 2>&1
```

Given that I push into a repo on the server.

I could do this with a cron job, but it seems kind of missing the point. Is there some way to initiate this after I pushed via SSH?

Comment: I just tried out Hudson/Jenkins. This is a little more powerful, but does what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in native git with a post-receive hook. Since you shouldn't be pushing to a non-bare repo, you'll need a script along the lines of this

```
#!/bin/sh
target="/tmp/math"
exec > "$target/$(date +%s)_$(uuidgen).log" 2>&1
mkdir -p "$target"
GIT_WORK_TREE="$target" git checkout -f
cd "$target"
make
```

Put that in `hooks/post-receive` inside the bare repo, and you should be all set (note that this will not create `$TARGET_DIR`, you'll have to do that manually)

Comment: That sounds way easier than the whole Jenkins. I'll give it a try in the next days.

Comment: I created the hook, but it is not executed when I push. If I call `.git/hooks/post-reveive` manually on the server, it works though.

Comment: @queueoverflow: Make sure the permissions are right (i.e. which user is the hook called as?), and the working directory fits.